# How to plot phase trajectories of a spherically symmetric fluid flow system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, graphing-functions, classical-mechanics

I am trying to plot the phase trajectories of a spherically symmetric fluid flow having the following equation of motion:
$$\frac{dv}{dr}=\frac{2v}{r^2}\frac{r-1}{v^2-1}$$

Integrating the above equation gives the velocity profile of the flow expressed as
$$\frac{v^2}{2}-\ln (v)=\ln(r^2)+\frac{2}{r}+K$$
where $K$ is the integration constant.

The phase trajectories can be obtained by plotting this equation to obtain plots like

[image: phase plot]

In the above equations, $u/c_s=v$ and $r_B$ is set to unity.

The various curves are obtained according to the following conditions on the value of $K$:

- $K=-1.5$: The red curves marked 'accretion' and 'wind'.
- $K<-1.5$: The grey curves marked 'unphysical'.
- $K>-1.5$: The green curves marked 'subsonic' and 'supersonic'.

> **I am having trouble to understand how to plot the curves. Can someone help me to understand the algorithm for the problem?**

I tried the online [phase plane plotter](https://aeb019.hosted.uark.edu/pplane.html) to obtain the following plot:

[image: phase space]

Comment: @Moo No, I couldn't solve the problem. The plot that I obtained was from an online software, but I am interested to write a code to obtain the results. So I require to understand the algorithm.

Comment: @Moo Thank you for the links. I will try to write a program for my problem. However, it would be helpful for me if you could write an answer to understand the underlying concepts clearly.